# Text retain on changing orientation of Mobile

Tags: android, orientation

AS you can see that i am new in android , and i am in problem . In my log-in form when i change orientation of my mobile then filled text in edit-text became loss.

How to retain my text even on changing orientation of mobile.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use in your android menifest file in your activity:

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

and in your activity file handle your orientation change case like this:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    //SET YOUR CURRENT TEXT OF EDITTEXT TO IT
    YOUR_EDIT_TEXT.setText("YOUR TEXT");
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Please don't do this. Avoid overriding configuration changes in your app's Manifest. You should handle your Activity's state according to Android docs (http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html)